# Annual average between period of years in BI

Tags: powerbi

I have filtered a certain range of years that present the following data:

year 2015 = 72

year 2016 = 77

year 2017 = 61

year 2018 = 97

I already have the following data:
variation in the period: 34.7%
variation in the last year: 6.5%

But I need to know how to arrive at the annual average, which in this case is equal to 10.4%.

[Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jehsy.png)

[Edit]

First to find variation in the period:

```
QT_VG_FIRST = CALCULATE(Discentes[QT_VG_TOTAL_SUM],FIRSTNONBLANK(Discentes[NU_YEAR_CENSO].[Year],0))
QT_VG_LAST = CALCULATE(Discentes[QT_VG_TOTAL_SUM],DATESYTD(Discentes[NU_YEAR_CENSO],"12/31"))
```

Variation in the period:

```
QT_VG_TOTAL_VARIACAO_PERIOD = DIVIDE([QT_VG_LAST]-[QT_VG_FIRST],[QT_VG_FIRST],0)
```

And variation in the last year:

```
QT_VG_PENÚLTIMO = CALCULATE([QT_VG_TOTAL_SUM],DATEADD(LASTNONBLANK(Discentes[NU_YEAR_CENSO],0),-1,YEAR))
```

Comment: Are the period variation and the annual variations, measures? Could you share the Dax for both? Edit you question with them.

Comment: Yes @SamNseir, edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm hoping the below works for you. I'm making some guesses but hopefully you get the idea.

```
AVG_VARIACAO_PERIOD = 
  var yearTable = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    Discentes[NU_YEAR_CENSO].[Year],
    "VARIACAO", [QT_VG_TOTAL_VARIACAO_PERIOD]
  )
  RETURN AVERAGEX(yearTable , [VARIACAO])


AVG_VARIACAO_YEAR = 
  var yearTable = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    Discentes[NU_YEAR_CENSO].[Year],
    "VARIACAO", [QT_VG_TOTAL_VARIACAO_YEAR]
  )
  RETURN AVERAGEX(yearTable , [VARIACAO])
```

Comment: Hi Sam. Your solution ended up clarifying an idea that will help me solve this problem. Thank you very much..